# Why won't objects appear in motion tracking?

Tags: tracking

I set up a motion track, then said set up tracking scene. I added a monkey, a subsurf modifier, and just a red material that I clicked shadeless on. When I render it shows up ghostlike and you can't see it good. In the 3d view it shows the image and the monkey.[image: you can see the monkey]
[image: Here is a picture of the uvs and compositor nodes(I have none)][image: This is the scene with the markers]

Comment: can you add images that show not only the result,  but how the scene and the compositor nodes are setup?

Comment: @cegaton Wait I just realized! I don't have any compositor nodes! Do I need to put some on the monkey head?

Comment: @cegaton I added some new pics!